# JSON Object empty when creating it from a String

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to create a JSON Object from a String. The String looks like this: `{"case":"getAllProducts"}`.

Why is `jobj` always empty?

```
String received = textMessage.getText();
            
System.out.println(received);       //{"case":"getAllProducts"} - perfect
            
JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(received, JsonObject.class);
            
System.out.println(jobj);           //{} - why empty???
            
String reqCase = jobj.get("case").getAsString();
```

I already checked out other articles here where its done exactly like I did. I can't find my problem here..

Comment: Cannot reproduce and the code you've provided should work as expected. Which Gson version are you using?

Comment: And just to be sure: The `JsonObject.class` is `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, right? There might be other libraries which also have classes with this name, and maybe you imported one of them by accident.

Comment: @Marcono1234 I don't think so: the `.get("case").getAsString()` method invocation chain tells it's (most likely) Gson. I believe there was an issue with the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
new Gson().fromJson(received, JsonObject.class);
```

it should be

```
new Gson().fromJson(received, YourClass.class);
```

where YourClass is a user defined class having attributes same as the attributes in your JSON.

Comment: Downvoted. The OP is asking why deserialization for `JsonObject` is not working (I have doubt it doesn't work), that can hold **everything** the `{ ... }` JSON literal contains, and not limited to `YourClass` structure only. Semantically, both your code examples are equivalent and don't resolve the issue that obviously left intact.